# Get nodes within 1km walking distance of a GPS location OSMNX

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

Given a (lat,lng) point and an all type OSMNX network, how can I find which nodes in the graph are within 1km walking distance from the point?

I was thinking about calculating the great circle distance between each node and the point and checking whether it is at most 1km, but I do not believe this will be very accurate since the topology of the network will be ignored.

Comment: If you have a graph, you just do a recursive depth first search until you reach nodes beyond 1km.  Make sure you don't revisit nodes you've already seen.

Answer (score 1):

This OSMnx usage [example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/v1.0.1/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb) demonstrates how.

Comment: I see that this example uses a 'walk' network type. Should I define a subgraph of the 'all' network type graph that includes only edges that are walkable? My original graph needs to be 'all' type since I need to work on both drivable edges and walkable edges. Does something like the following work: G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='all') filtr = ['footway'] e = [(u, v, k) for u, v, k, d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True) if filtr not in d['highway']] G.remove_edges_from(e).

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm using folium and Django. Python ended up in a never ending for loop, when `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used OSMnx before, but the [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) seems to be very good. And no, you are right that calculating the Haversine (great circle) distance or Euclidean distance will not give you the actual walking distance. The whole point of OSMnx is that it takes real-life street networks into account.

One of the functions that seem to be based on the actual network is
`osmnx.distance.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight='length')`.

You might use this function to calculate the shortest distance between all nodes and your point ... and then select those whose shortest distance is below 1 km.

I do not know, however, how walking paths, cicling paths and streets for cars can be differentiated in OSMnx. You might need to consult the documentation for more details or [open an issue in the OSMnx GITHUB repo](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx).